# OutOfMemoryError when sending image from android to php server

Tags: java, php, android

Im triing to send image from my sdcard to php server ...
I create 2 class : the first is MainActivity.java and the second is Base64.java which encodeBytes in Base64 Format.

My MainActivity.java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    InputStream inputStream;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1378889572299.jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
         ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));
Log.e("ok", "1");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myserver.com/upload_image.php");
Log.e("ok", "3");
try {
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
Log.e("ok", "4");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.e("ok", "5");

    String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    }

    public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

        String res = "";
         StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
         inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
         final int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
        }
    });

         if (contentLength < 0){
         }
         else{
                byte[] data = new byte[512];
                int len = 0;
                try
                {
                    while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                    {
                        buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try
                {
                    inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..
                final String res2 = res;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result : " + res2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
                //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
         }
         return res;
    }
}
```

I have this erreur :

```
........OutOfMemoryError
….at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.(AbstractStringBuilder.java:81)
….at java.lang.StringBuilder.(StringBuilder.java:68)
….at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:98)
….at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encode(URLEncodedUtils.java:184)
….at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:163)
….at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:71)
….at com.example.imageuploadonserver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
```

line 43 is:
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

I make some change in my code ... and i replace the image source from my sdcard to my drawabel.ic_luncher :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(“/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1378889572299.jpg”);
```

by this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

and it work succseffuly !!!!

I googled a lot, but either I used the wrong keywords or there are no simple solutions on the internet. I hope somebody here can help me.

Best regards and thanks in advance, Fadel.

Comment: How large is your image? (not filesize, but pixels)

Comment: My image size:
width:2560
Height: 1920

Comment: My image type: image.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the image you are trying to upload is very big in size. You need to scale it down while creating bitmap. The resolution of your ic_launcher png is very low so it didn't cause any trouble while creating bitmap.

Check this link for loading bitmaps efficietly- 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: mmmmmmmm .... i thing you are right !!!
if it's right i will put your answer as true (y)

Comment: O.M.G !!! Big thanks for you @AshishKumar .... !!! know i understand what happened !! yup its about the image resolution .... i enter in the link you linked to me and i get the picture about how to resolve the resolutions of pictures where we wont to send it to serve !!!!
It Worked !!! again big thanks for you Ashish !!! :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that your image is about 5Mo as it's a picture from your camera.

1. When you load it as a bitmap, your heap size grow by 5Mo.
2. Then you convert it to a byte array with som compression, so your heap size is growing by maybe 4Mo again => 9Mo
3. Then you base64encode it to a string, again the heap grow by 4Mo => 13Mo
4. Then, by adding it to a NameValu¨Pair as a string, i think it copy the string (not sure here) and the heap grow again => 17Mo
5. And then when you add it as entity, it encodes the content and the heap is growing again => 22Mo

You should try to release the memory when you don't need it anymore :

1. use bitmap.recycle() after step 2.
2. set your bite array to null after step 3
3. set your string to null after step 4 (not sure)

You will release about 9 to 14Mo by doing so

But in all case, by encoding it (base64Encode or UrlEncode) your heap size will grow of twice the bitmap size. Abetter way should be to write the content of the file to the HTTP stream will reading from the file.

Comment: Did You Mean that isnt important to encoding images in base64 befor sending it to server ???
@Zoubiock

Comment: No, I mean that you have to release the memory that you don't need anymore. After that, when you encode an object, it's stored twice during the encoding process, so if you could avoid this step (by changes on the server side) it will be better.

Comment: Ahhh !! Okkkk !!! I will try it !! If its right i will put your answer as true (y)...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading all the data into memory at once, I would use a [ChunkedOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/io/ChunkedOutputStream.html) 
that streams the data in chunks. If you're careful with this, you can upload images of unlimited size because its never necessary to have the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with Client <-> Server WebServices, loading a whole request or response data into a String or any memory object is bad practice and should be avoided  as much as possible. It's avoidable in many scenarios.

**Why should it be avoided?**

Because in many scenarios you never have any guarantee about the data's size and it will often lead you to OOM exceptions.

**How should you do?**

For most requests data, you can build it while you are sending it (XML, JSON, Whatever-serialization) and you don't need to reed the whole structure in memory to be able to serialize it.

For most answers data, you can parse the objects out of the stream and save it in you database or discard whatever part of the stream you don't need. Without loading the whole response as a String.

**In your specific case**, you have a File on disk that is an image you wish to compress. Use the standard library or whatever other image library to covert it to 90% JPEG to another file. Then you can stream the file directly to the httpPost.entity's output stream.

It's even probable that some libraries (maybe even the standard library?) offers you the possibility to get an InputStream with the compressed image directly from your first image file.

In both cases, encapsulate your first InputStream in another InputStream that does the Base64 conversion and you're there.

That way you'll never need to load more than a few kilobytes at a time into memory, for stream buffers.